# Angular's ng-class is not updating while the value being evaluated is

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

So, I have no idea what is going on here. It is either an extremely obvious misunderstanding, or an bug between ui-router and ng-class. My template looks like this (with Jade syntax):

```
button.back(ng-class="{ 'hidden':  {{'index.blog.article' | isState}}    }") back ){{'index.blog.article' | isState}})
```

And in the live view, when the state 'index.blog.article' is **not active**, you see:

```
<button ng-class="{ 'hidden':  false }" class="back ng-binding"> back false</button>
```

As you would expect. However, when the state **is active**, you see this:

```
<button ng-class="{ 'hidden':  true }" class="back ng-binding"> back true</button>
```

except that the class doesn't actually change. So, the value in the template gets updated, but ng-class doesn't get evaluated? What gives?

Comment: Also, I'm using Angular 1.4-beta3, and the latest ui-router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
ng-class="isState('article')?'hidden':''"
```

or

```
ng-class="{'hidden':isState('article')}"
```

with  isState is a function on the scope compare $state.current.name with the param and returning true or false

see my jsfiddle that its works together with button  http://jsfiddle.net/5aj4qy81/ or http://jsfiddle.net/5aj4qy81/1/

**Edit** This next solution works also if your back button is outside of your controller just realize ui-router has this function isState calling it 'is' .

So you can add $state to $rootScope

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
 $rootScope.$state = $state;
 $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
```

});

and then using this in your back button

```
ng-class="{'hidden':$state.is('article')}"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5aj4qy81/3/

Answer (score 4):

For some reason I am not 100% sure why but `<button>` tag will not update the class, neither will `<input type="button">`. The work around this is to declare the class with whatever you are binding to such as

```
<button ng-class="{ hidden: true, unHidden: false }" class="{{ index.blog.article }}" />
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cw42tjuw/)

*Inspect the first button and you will see the class change

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't seem to fix it in my case. Happens on regular <div>s also.

Comment: Actually, this is weird. I can see the "true/false" value in the class, but it will not add the class stated in the ng-class.

Comment: ...and other classes in the ng-class tag will update. I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing the single quote's?  so your code should look like this:

```html
<div ng-class="{ hidden: true }" ...> back true</div>
```